# if you create your own OS , do you need to make your own compilers/interpreters to write normal programs?

Tags: python, c, operating-system

out of curiosity i am learning OS development and attempting to create an operating system for a raspberry pi , my end goal of this project is to be able to run python programs on it. So if i have a bare bones os kernel, how would i get to the stage of being able to run applications (maybe like a terminal) on it and would i need to write my own python interpreter to run python programs?

Comment: You will have to port python yourself to your platform because your platform is not linux/windows/macOs etc

Comment: Perhaps [this should help](https://devguide.python.org/porting/)

Answer (score 3):

#### You first need to understand what is an operating system.

My recommendation: **read a good [textbook on operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)** then [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)

Notice that not every OS has files. For example, [EROS](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix02/full_papers/shapiro/shapiro.pdf) don't have any. Some toy OSes have toy [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) (à la [FAT16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system)) without any [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)).

#### You then need to understand what is a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), an [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)), a [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode), a [programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language), an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), a [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)), [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)....

My recommendation: **read the [*Dragon Book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) then [*Programming Language Pragmatics*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) then [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://christian.queinnec.org/WWW/LiSP.html)**

At last, you should be interested by sites, such as [OSDEV](https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page), giving concrete advice about operating system development. Obviously, an OS is depending on the hardware (perhaps an emulator such as [Qemu](https://www.qemu.org/)) it is running on.

### A lot of operating systems, and the [Python](https://python.org/) interpreter, are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source).

My recommendation: **study their source code**. For Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/), see http://kernelfornewbies.org/ ; look also, for inspiration, into [OpenBSD](https://www.openbsd.org/) and [GNU Hurd](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd.html) and [FreeRTOS](https://freertos.org/) and [Contiki](https://www.contiki-ng.org/) and [MirageOS](https://mirage.io/).

> So if i have a bare bones os kernel,

You need to **document its design** and, if it has some, its [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). Some OSes don't have any syscalls, e.g. [Singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28operating_system%29). Linux has many [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

> being able to run applications (maybe like a terminal)

In 2020, real world terminals do not exist any more (except in museums). A famous one was the [VT220](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT220). You might want to code a *terminal emulator* understanding [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). These are complex things. Maybe you want to code something like [xterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm), but then you'll need some [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) (e.g. driving [HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI)). For Linux, read [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html).

Today (in 2020), most [keyboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_keyboard) are [USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB). Your OS need an USB driver, whose details depend upon your actual hardware and USB controller.

Be prepared to the idea of writing (or borrowing, or reusing from [GNU/Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU/Linux_naming_controversy)) millions of lines of C code. **Study existing open source code.**

#### budget a decade of full time work.

Comment: It can take years to finish.

Comment: I would say a decade. YMMV